# Отображать ли в ленте большие картинки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я заметил проблему, что когда загружаю в ленту картинки более 4 000px x 3 000px, то начинает глючить скролл, что делать?

Comment: Изменяйте средствами PHP размер изображения.
http://sanchiz.net/blog/resizing-images-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Откройте файл изображений в каком либо графическом редакторе, например Photoshop;
2. Нажмите на третий элемент вехнего меню - image;
3. выберите пункт image-size;
4. Измените размер изображения (уменьшите его);
5. Замените исходное изображение новым;
6. Если необходимо, через CSS задайте необходимый размер изображению, например:

   **img {
       width: 400px;
       height: 300px;
     }**

или

```
background-size: 400px auto;
```

Comment: нет. Я имел ввиду натуральную ширину, даже если CSS изменить будет тормозить.  Посмотрите, как в ВК это сделано, там все изображения не больше 600px, а когда жмешь открываются настоящие размеры. Как изменить через php, размеры картинки?

Comment: http://fancybox.net/ так?